# How to access & display measure description in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs

I have an SSAS tabular model with many measures. Each measure has a the Description property defined in the tabular model. In my SSRS report, I would like the measure Descriptions to be displayed (either as a field in the report or a tooltip).

How do I achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a **Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services** data source to your SSRS report, to be able to access it. Please see this article, [**How to create a simple SSRS Report using a SSAS Tabular model database**](https://www.sqlshack.com/create-simple-ssrs-report-using-ssas-tabular-model-database/) for a step-by-step guide.

Comment: I know how to use a Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services data source and create a report using measures from that source. What I am asking is, after adding a  Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services data source to the SSRS report, how do I access the measure Description property?